# How can I import/export data to/from iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios

How do I import/export data to/from my iPhone app using email?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

visit this blog post - http://www.raywenderlich.com/1980/how-to-import-and-export-app-data-via-email-in-your-ios-app